# Changing headers display and order from a recordset to excel sheet

Tags: sql, excel, vba, recordset

I have an excel sheet that I use as database, and a search form that allow user to search for information, based on some criterias, and display the filtered results in a new sheet.

I am using SQL to fetch data, and display them to the user.

I use something like top open connection, then to create a record set and pass my sql request to it

```
m_Connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

Set OpenRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    OpenRecordset.Open sql, GetConnection(), 3, 3, &H1

Set rst = OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Database$] Where " & Myconditions & ";")
```

Everything works fine, but I need to allow users to choose the column headers names and order that may be different from what i have in the sheet from which i make my select that i call database

We need this because users are in different countries, so the display name will be configured based on the country of the user, but also we want to allow user to change the display name and order of the fields based on their needs and because the display name may be too long (multi line).

My real "database" sheet is about 110 columns, and about 1000 records (rows).

I can't publish the real data because it's confidential, but to help you understand me, I created this example that represent what I have

let us suppose I have this "database"

[image]

the user enter this search screen to select the information he needs from the database

[image]

I wish that the user will get this result and not in the same order and display of the database

[image]

as you can see, the display names and orders of the columns in the result page is different from the "database" sheet

I would like to create a configuration page, in which the user can specify the display name he wants and the order in which he wants the fields to appears. something like that

[image]

Is there any fast way to do that directly in my Recordset in SQL/EXCEL or I should after I fetch data, change the headers in excel sheet using vba ? if so, I have to make a kind of array in vba that contains both database Names and display names and replace the names of the database by its corresponding just before I show the result page shows ? 
any suggestions ? 
same question about the order of the fields, how to sort them based on the order the user choosed ? any fast way ?

Thanks for anyone who can help with the best way to do that

Comment: You would need to build the SQL by the field names wanting to be shown and then alias them using `as` something like `select [" & range("a1").value & "] as [" range("b1"),value & "],.......`

Comment: I see what you mean, So the record set doesn't have a property or method allowing to affect a display field, right ? Regarding your suggestion, it's not bad, but if there is something better to do for over 100 fields it will be great, if not I will do the way you propose. 
Do you think this is better ? or for example making 2 dimensional array, in vba, first column the real name, second colum display name, and after i paste my record set in the result page, i loop through colums and replace them one by one based on my array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following, it loops through the data range based on the number of rows in the range being the min and max of positions available, it looks for these rankings in turn, in column C, then checks if shown, then add's the field name and it's alias to an array.  This array is then joined.  So using data similar to yours, in columns of the the same ordering, I called:

`GenerateOrderedSQL("table 1",range("a2:d6"),3,4)`  A1:D1 contained headers

This called my function

```
Function GenerateOrderedSQL(strInputTable As String, _
                        rngRangeForSelection As Excel.Range, _
                        lngOrderColumn As Long, _
                        lngShowColumn As Long) As String

Dim l As Long
Dim fPos As Long
Dim lfPos As Long
Dim a() As Variant

l = rngRangeForSelection.Rows.Count

ReDim a(l)

For fPos = 1 To l

    lfPos = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(fPos, _
                    rngRangeForSelection.Columns(lngOrderColumn), 0)

    If rngRangeForSelection.Cells(lfPos, lngShowColumn).Value = "Yes" Then
        a(fPos-1) = "[" & rngRangeForSelection.Cells(lfPos, 1) & _
                        "] AS [" & rngRangeForSelection.Cells(lfPos, 2) & "]"
        a(fPos-1) = a(fPos-1) & IIf(fPos < l, ",", vbNullString)
    End If

Next

Debug.Print "SELECT " & Join(a, vbNullString) & " FROM [" & strInputTable; "]"

End Function`
```

This gave the following

`SELECT [Fname] AS [First Name],[Lname] AS [Last Name],[Zip] AS [Zip],[City] AS [City] FROM [table 1]`

Comment: thanks a lot for trying to help, I will try it next week at work because I don't work during the weekend and my excel and database are at work. By the way, if you can add some comments to your code it will be very helpfull if one day someone else needs to understand it, it becomes easiar..thanks again and i will let u know if it solved my problem

Comment: thanks a lot, I made a first test on a sample database and your code create the correct SQL select. I have now to prepare the real data to work on it, but it will takes me few days to prepare all, and will come back to tag it as resolved if all is ok.I will vote +1 waiting final confirmation before I pick your answer as resolved.
By the way, if I wasn't using the SQL, do you have an idea how could we do the same by just using VBA without sql ? it may be interesting to have both methods and helpfull to me or any other user who doesn't use sql in his code.

Comment: Thanks a lot I forgot to come back to tag is as resolved. Your solution was very good, still have 2 little problems to make it works perfect, first I had to add the dollar symbol to the database name

GenerateOrderedSQL = "SELECT " & Join(a, vbNullString) & " FROM [" & strInputTable & "$];"

The second was to 
GenerateOrderedSQL = Replace(GenerateOrderedSQL, ", FROM [", " FROM [")

if I don't want to show all the fields, for example my database is 100 field and I just want to treat 20, I will get with your code a ","  before the from which will make the code fails.